# Xamarin.iOS failed to synchronize SDK with unknown error

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to connection to the Xamarin Build Host (MAC OS) from my Visual Studio (Windows PC). Every time I'm paring VS and Build Host I'm getting proposal to sync SDKs:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wc4q7apmjxzcxru/shot_140320_170111.png

and every time I'm pressing the OK button I get the following error:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kka5c9kqh9f65nn/shot_140320_165146.png

Visual Studio is crashed with the following error fetched from the EventLog:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentNullException
Stack:
   at System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper..ctor(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(System.Windows.Window, System.String, System.String, System.Windows.MessageBoxButton, System.Windows.MessageBoxImage)
   at Mono.IOS.VisualStudio.Utilities.SdkStatus.NotifySdkIconClick(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon.OnBalloonTipClicked()
   at System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon+NotifyIconNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)

Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 12.0.30110.0, time stamp: 0x52cfb65a
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.16496, time stamp: 0x52b3e015
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00012eec
Faulting process id: 0x16ec
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf447df8795b46
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 6a73a398-b071-11e3-bec4-7ce9d3fe3dda
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Support didn't answer my question yet.

Comment: AFAIK the fact that it keeps complaining about unsynced SDKs is a bug. But if you reported this to support@xamarin.com already, please be patient. They will eventually get back to you.

Comment: Yeah, I get the unsynced SDK message all the time and it never actually finishes.

Comment: So you just ignore it and continue deployment? The issue that I couldn't deploy after that using iOS build host. I was sure that this issue is somehow connected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to fix the issue by switching to the Alpha channel of Xamarin software.
After updating both Windows and Mac I got a working environment, no "SDK sync is required" notifications and an ability to deploy a build to my iPhone connected to the Mac from Visual Studio